# Term for "relative-orthogonality" of two random binary vectors

Tags: notation

We expect two random bipolar vectors $x,y\in\{-1,1\}^n$ to have dot product of $0$ such that:
$\mathbb{E}[x \cdot y]=0$.
Accordingly, these vectors are termed "orthogonal".
Is there any term for the relationship of two random binary vectors $x,y\in\{0,1\}^n$ which we expect to have dot product of $\frac{1}{4}$ their length, such that $\mathbb{E}[x \cdot y]=\frac{n}{4}$?